# Error slicing list of dictionaries by key?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, slice

I have a Pandas `Series` which contains dictionaries holding two key-value pairs each.

Here is a picture of the data (apologies for size)

[image]

How would I go about getting all of the `'C'` key's values, like `[10000000.0, 3162277.66 ..., 1000000.0, ...]` here? I've already tried `sorted_combos.iloc[:, 0]['C']`, but that gives me a `KeyError`, so I am stumped.

How am I do to this for future reference? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a list comprehension to loop over all the dictionaries. In this case, the code would be `[dic['C'] for dic in sorted_combos.iloc[:,0]]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! 

It didn't occur to me that accessing dictionaries by key needed loops, and it still is mysterious to me, since `dic['C']` in the list comprehension seems equivalent to what I was trying to do, `sorted_combos.iloc[:, 0]['C']`, which did not work.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You have to get the `['C']` value for each individual dictionary, `sorted_combos.iloc[:, 0]` itself is a list-like object and does not have keys.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Great start for a new stackoverflow account :).